# groovy-how to get the values of same field in response arrays

Tags: groovy, soapui

This is the response I am getting from soapui.

```
<PageList>
   <offset>0</offset> 
   <totalLength>2</totalLength> 
   <result> 
     <Id>9</Id> 
     <Name>Cake</Name> 
     <Price>80</Price> 
     <quantity>1</quantity>
   </result> 
   <result>
     <Id>13</Id> 
     <Name>Tea</Name> 
     <Price>10</Price> 
     <quantity>5</quantity> 
   </result> 
   <result> 
     <Id>15</Id> 
     <Name>Cofee</Name> 
     <Price>15</Price> 
     <quantity>10</quantity> 
   </result> 
</PageList>
```

How to display the name field separately like 
Cake,Tea,Cofee
using groovy script

Comment: Did you try anything?  This is basically what most examples in the documentation show you how to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the list of names in the following way:

```
def xml = '''<PageList>
   <offset>0</offset> 
   <totalLength>2</totalLength> 
   <result> 
     <Id>9</Id> 
     <Name>Cake</Name> 
     <Price>80</Price> 
     <quantity>1</quantity>
   </result> 
   <result>
     <Id>13</Id> 
     <Name>Tea</Name> 
     <Price>10</Price> 
     <quantity>5</quantity> 
   </result> 
   <result> 
     <Id>15</Id> 
     <Name>Cofee</Name> 
     <Price>15</Price> 
     <quantity>10</quantity> 
   </result> 
</PageList>'''

def slurped = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)
def names = slurped.result.Name.collect { it.text() }
println names
```

Comment: I am not able to pass this value to another test request

Comment: @Reshu, this is a different question. You're asking how to get the values.